# Can you broadcast data to nearby devices without requesting permissions from the devices and the user broadcasting?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, broadcast, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to make an app as a hobby and I need to know, is it possible to broadcast to all nearby devices without requesting each and every device's permission? 
If it is possible to ask the user to accept **ALL** incoming connections and send connection requests to devices without making the user choose which device it would be great for me.
I found that you can connect up to 7 peers with multipeer but the user have to choose every device he wants to connect with.
Any option of nearby broadcasting would help me here, 
Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Accepting invitation is easy, instead of prompting the advertiser to accept, simply set the `invitationHandler` to true.

For example, in my implementation, I have an MPManager class:

```
func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: NSData?, invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession) -> Void) {
    self.invitationHandler = invitationHandler

    delegate?.invitationWasReceived(peerID.displayName)
}
```

And the delegate method:

```
func invitationWasReceived(fromPeer: String) {
       self.appDelegate.cManager!.invitationHandler(true, self.appDelegate.cManager!.session)
       self.connectingLabel.text = "Connecting"
}
```

For the browser side, you can similarly automatically send the invitations to any peer it finds, the question is when to stop searching for peers and continue with what you want to do once they are all connected.

Have you checked [PeerKit](https://github.com/jpsim/PeerKit)? I bills itself as exactly that, a zero-config approach. I briefly checked it for what I was doing, but didn't quite match my needs. Maybe it matches yours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, I was checking about Bluetooth Low Energy, but having problems researching about it online, I am pretty much stuck, I will try your suggestion, it seems that it would work, thanks again :)